# Button redirecting to a page without me requesting this behavior

Tags: javascript, html, select

I have a button and I'm trying to get it to insert html into a column based on options in a select box. I've looked over my code a dozen times and can't understand why it acts the way it does: instead of inserting the code into the div and displaying it I'm redirected to another webpage ".../newlsetters-%newsletteryear%". Not sure what is making this happen. Any help would be appreciated!

```
<h1>KMVCSS Newsletters</h1> <h1 style="font-weight: 100">2014 - 2017</h1>
<div class="n-body">
<form>
<select id="nbox" name="newsletters">
<option value="2017">Newsletter 2017</option>
</select>

<button id="nbutton" onclick="displayNewsletter();">Get Newsletter 
Link</button>
</form>

<div class="n-row">
<div id="col">
</div>
</div>
</div>

<script>
function displayNewsletter() {
    var selectedNewsletter = document.getElementById("nbox").value;
    var col= document.getElementById("col");
    var a = "<h2>2017</h2> <img alt='newsletter' src='http://clone.kmvcss.org/wpcontent/themes/nu2013/images/2017-Newsletter.png' width='60px' height='180px'/> <a href='https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0vGa180vtK9aDlPZlFIMTRmcDJvZ0l5Ti1WMGxIV3RMV3RV'>";


    if (selectedNewsletter === "2017") {
        col.innerHtml = a;
}

</script>
```

Comment: `innerHtml` should be `innerHTML`. You also need to close your `<a>` tag.

Answer (score 4):

`<button id="nbutton" type='button' onclick="displayNewsletter();">Get Newsletter 
Link</button>`

by default it's a submit button and browser performs forms' submission with subsequent redirect to `url` specified in the form(in your case it's empty).

Comment: except for `IE` which default is `"button"`

Comment: so do i take the html out of the form tags? is it only a submission button by default when the button is a child of the form tag?

Comment: the problem in your case: no button type specified. So you have to add `type="button"` to you button. Then the js click handler will be triggered.

Answer (score 1):

you need to add return false to your function

```
<h1>KMVCSS Newsletters</h1> <h1 style="font-weight: 100">2014 - 2017</h1>
<div class="n-body">
<form action="post" action="">
<select id="nbox" name="newsletters">
<option value="2017">Newsletter 2017</option>
</select>

<button id="nbutton" onclick="displayNewsletter();return false;">Get Newsletter 
Link</button>
</form>

<div class="n-row">
<div id="col">xxx</div>
</div>
</div>

<script>
function displayNewsletter() {
    var selectedNewsletter = document.getElementById("nbox").value;
    var col= document.getElementById("col");
    var a = "<h2>2017</h2> <img alt='newsletter' src='http://clone.kmvcss.org/wpcontent/themes/nu2013/images/2017-Newsletter.png' width='60px' height='180px'/> <a href='https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0vGa180vtK9aDlPZlFIMTRmcDJvZ0l5Ti1WMGxIV3RMV3RV'>xxx</a>";


    if (selectedNewsletter == "2017") {
        col.innerHTML = a;
    }

    return false;
}

</script>
```

Comment: This code does work:
https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FLOMQWJW6ROV - try adding it to a normal web page and run it. Not using jsfiddle.

Comment: you're right. I also checked it before writing comment and it didn't work somehow :) I'll delete my comment.